# "Big integer literals are not available" when integrating Discord.JS in Tauri

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discord.js, tauri

I'm trying to write a tauri app (react+ts+vite) that uses discord.js. However, when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
node_modules/discord-api-types/payloads/v9/permissions.js:17:16: ERROR: Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
```

Is it even possible to use tauri and discord.js together, or do I have to write separate application and "discord bot"?

I understand that it would be wiser to ask a question about the error itself, but after browsing the Internet a little, I did not find anything, or other than setting compilerOptions to es2020, but this did not help me. I also found an issue on github that discussed discord.js in the browser, but it's out of date.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75576741/how-to-solve-error-big-integer-literals-are-not-available-in-the-configured-tar

Answer (score 1):

You would need to target your build to the latest version inside of the vite:

So `esnext` would work best, or you can target `es2020`-`es2024`

```js
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      target: 'esnext',
    },
  },
})
```