# How to solve error "Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment" on vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, optimization, vite, vitest

I am using **vite**, **react** and **typescript** then i got this error, anyone knows how to solve it ?

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.9",
    "@composedb/cli": "^0.3.1",
    "@composedb/client": "^0.3.1",
    "@didtools/pkh-ethereum": "^0.0.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.2",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
    "cytoscape": "^3.22.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "did-session": "^1.0.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "web3": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cytoscape": "^3.19.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

Logs:

> ```
> ✘ [ERROR] Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
>
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:231:16:
>   231 │         e = e / 2n;
>       ╵                 ~~
>
> ✘ [ERROR] Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
>
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:232:17:
>   232 │         b = b ** 2n % n;
>       ╵                  ~~
>
> 7:04:56 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies: Error: Build failed with 68 errors:
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:21:14: ERROR:
> Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:27:20: 
> ERROR:
> Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:27:26: ERROR:
> Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:47:13: ERROR:
> Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1")
> node_modules/bigint-mod-arith/dist/esm/index.browser.js:47:24: ERROR:
> Big integer literals are not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2019", "firefox78", "safari13.1") ...
> at failureErrorWithLog 
> [...]
> ```

I tried, deleting **node_modules** and **pnpm-lock-yaml** and reinstalling them but the problem is still there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `tsconfig.json` file and any other compilation configuration. Why are you targeting such old browser versions? Safari is the problem as it only got [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#browser_compatibility) support in v14

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it on **vite 3.2.x** and **4.1.x** *(with Svelte instead of React, but it should work)* by defining the following vite config's options:

- `optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions.target`
- `optimizeDeps.global`
- `optimizeDeps.esbuildOptions.supported.bigint`
- `build.target`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
// import react, svelte and other needs...

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default ({ mode }) => {

  return defineConfig({
    
    optimizeDeps: { //  optimizedeps
      esbuildOptions: {
        target: "esnext", 
        // Node.js global to browser globalThis
        define: {
          global: 'globalThis'
        },
        supported: { 
          bigint: true 
        },
      }
    }, 

    build: {
      target: ["esnext"], //  build.target
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: Used this Vite config in a NuxtJS project and solved my static build deployment.
Although i had to set my target to 'es2020'

Comment: @flydev may I ask how you were able to figure this out?I want to get better at debugging issues like these.

Comment: @nxmohamad create a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), invite me and let's have a discussion.

Comment: @flydev created - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/255046/vite-config-deep-dive?tab=general

Answer (score 3):

Simplified the @flydev answer a bit:

`vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build: {
    target: 'esnext', // you can also use 'es2020' here
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      target: 'esnext', // you can also use 'es2020' here
    },
  },
})
```

Also, make sure your Typescript target is high enough:

`tsconfig.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES2020", // you can also use higher value
  // ...
}
```